# Why doesn't the Graphical Layout view change when I update the background color of my ActionBar?

Tags: android

So I've changed the background of my Action Bar in a styles.xml file in my project. I thought that I was doing everything wrong because nothing was changing in the graphical layout, but when I uploaded it to my phone and ran it, the colors were fine.

I tried right clicking>open with> android layout editor, but the color of the Action Bar remains grey.

How can I update the preview in the 'Graphical Layout' tab of my activity_main.xml?

For reference: my styles.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.ActionBar.Background" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.StockGetter</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.StockGetter" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/OrangePeel</item>

    </style>
```

And the activity_main.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterStockSymbolEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:hint="@string/enter_stock_symbol"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enterStockSymbolButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/enterStockSymbolButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In the Graphical Layout view of Eclipse, there is a drop down selection box at the top of the tab which has a blue/grey star next to with the name of the currently applied theme name. Make sure you have the correct theme selected for your preview.

Comment: You're very welcome, please remember to accept the answer and all the best with your project! :)